# Modifying a protected field value is not seen in subclass instance

Tags: java, abstract, protected

This is a strange situation I've run into. I have an abstract base class that defines a protected field. There is also a public method that modifies the field. I then have some subclasses of the base class that make use of the field.

I've noticed that when I invoke the super-class method to modify the field, the change to the field's value does not seem to "carry through" to an instance of a subclass.

The other thing that needs to be mentioned is that the abstract class (and therefore its subclasses) implements `Runnable`. I wouldn't think that should have an effect on what I'm seeing, but multi-threading is not my forte.

Abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget implements Runnable {
  // Other fields and methods omitted for brevity.
  protected boolean running;

  public void shutDown() {
    running = false;
  }
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class ConcreteWidget extends AbstractWidget {
  // Other fields and methods omitted for brevity.

  @Override
  public void run() {
    running = true;
    while (running) {
      // ...
    }
    logger.info("Shutting down");
  }
}
```

So, when I finally invoke the `shutDown()` method, the subclass instance, running in a thread does not break from it's loop and return.

I've used the technique of modifying a boolean field from "the outside" to stop a "forever" thread many times before. I don't understand what's happening here.

UPDATE:

Below is an example of the code being called.

```
ConcreteWidget widet = new ConcreteWidget(...);
thread = new Thread(widget);
thread.start();
logger.info("Started");
```

...

```
logger.debug("shutting down");
widget.shutDown();

try {
  logger.debug("doing join on thread");
  thread.join();
  logger.debug("returned from join");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  logger.error("Exception", e);
}
```

The call to `join()` never returns.

UPDATE:

As requested I have included what I hope is a complete (enough) example of the code as I currently have it. NOTE: I have taken the suggestion and changed the protected `boolean` to `AtomicBoolean`.

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget implements Runnable {
  protected final AtomicBoolean   running  = new AtomicBoolean(true);
  public void shutDown() {
    running.set(false);
  }
}


public class ConcreteWidget extends AbstractWidget {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (running.get()) {
      // ... do stuff (including calling process() below)
    }
  }
  private void process() {
    try {
      // ... do stuff
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Exception", e);
      running.set(false);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

In the "main" logic:

```
  private void startService() {
    widget = new ConcreteWidget(...);
    thread = new Thread(widget);
    thread.start();
    logger.info("Started");
  }

  public void close() {
    logger.debug("shutting down service");
    widget.shutDown();

    try {
      logger.debug("doing join on service thread");
      thread.join();
      logger.debug("returned from join");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      logger.error("Exception", e);
    }
  }
```

BTW, it *still* does not work.

Comment: Can you share the code that calls `shutDown()`? Perhaps the issue is there.

Comment: Have you inadvertently declared `protected boolean running;` in the code you've left out of `ConcreteWidget` above for brevity?

Comment: I thought that as well and checked. No, I have not redefined the field in the subclasses.

Comment: This is probably more a problem of not using `volatile`/`synchronized` than anything else.

Comment: Then it seems like a `volatile` issue, though you'd expect the thread to see the updated value **eventually**... Still, it should be `volatile`, so...

Comment: Change the field type to AtomicBoolean, make it final, and change its state. That guarantees that any change will be visible from other threads. It won't be the case with boolean (unless you make it volatile, or you read and write it from synchronized blocks using the same lock). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility

Comment: Hmm, I was wondering if this could be a volatility issue (not that I understand what `volatile` does). So, then the fact that there's multi-threading involved **does** have something to do with this?

Comment: is widget thread looping inside while, maybe codes inside while loop running for one time and somehow it stuck in it (like waiting for something)

Comment: BTW, the widget and thread are started when the application is starting up. The close() method (to shut down the widget and join the thread) is called much later, after it has done a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is actually a simple one. By the time you call `widget.shutDown();`, the thread has not actually started, so when the thread actually starts, it sets `running` back to true, and never stops. Instead of using `running` to terminate the loop, use a separate `stopped` variable.

```
public abstract class AbstractWidget implements Runnable {
  // Other fields and methods omitted for brevity.
  private volatile boolean running = false;
  private valatile boolean stopped = false;

  public boolean isRunning() {
    return running;
  }

  public boolean hasStopped() {
    return stopped;
  }

  public void shutDown() {
    stopped = true;
  }
}

public class ConcreteWidget extends AbstractWidget {
  // Other fields and methods omitted for brevity.

  @Override
  public void run() {
    running = true;
    while (!stopped) {
      // ...
    }
    running = false;
    logger.info("Shutting down");
  }
}
```

With this setup, you might want to wait a while before stopping, if not the loop will never run at all.

```
ConcreteWidget widet = new ConcreteWidget(...);
thread = new Thread(widget);
thread.start();
logger.info("Started");
...

try {
  Thread.sleep(500); // <--
} catch (Exception e) {}
logger.debug("shutting down");
widget.shutDown();

try {
  logger.debug("doing join on thread");
  thread.join();
  logger.debug("returned from join");
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  logger.error("Exception", e);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still does not break the loop.

Comment: @JosephGagnon then it probably means that you're shutting down a widget that is not the same one as the one looping. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JosephGagnon I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run `widget.shutDown();` immediately after `thread.start();` ?

maybe `widget.shutDown();` has run before `running = true;` code inside `run()` method

Comment: No. The widget and thread are created more or less at startup and the close() method is called much later.

Answer (score 0):

[facepalm]

It turns out the problem was that the thread processing was hanging and never able to check the state of the `running` field. Once I corrected that problem, it worked just fine.

I did change my logic to use the `AtomicBoolean` instead of `boolean`, so thank you for that useful advice.